# jekyll site folder hierarchy list of subfolders only

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap, jekyll-theme

I have my Jekyll folder structure as

```
_includes
_layouts
_post
myFolder
   subMyFolder
   - readme.md
   subMyFolder2
   - README.md

   subMyFolder/subSub
   - readme.md
   - something.html
index.html
```

I wish to list all subMyFolders (just first level) without subSub folders and without files inside

My approach

```
{% for my_page in site.pages %}
  {% if my_page.url contains 'myFolder' %}
    {% if my_page.title %}
    <a class="page-link" href="{{ my_page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ my_page.title }}</a> •
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

get the job partially don however when a subFolder has multiple items inside (page1.html, page2.html etc) its repeated on the list as well as my _config.yml has

```
include:
 - subFolder
exclude:
 - README.md
```

but still, I get subFolder/README.html despite the fact i've excluded it..

I need only the folders hierarchy of myFolders

Answer (score 3):

The best I could do with `page.dir` this would print the myFolder subfolders, assuming there is no other page with myFolder on the item.path

```
{% assign tools = site.pages | where_exp: "item" , "item.path contains 'myFolder'"| map: 'dir' | uniq %}
<ul>
  {% for tool in tools %}
    <li><a class="page-link" href="{{ tool | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ tool }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

the problem this solution doesn't bring folder name if it's empty or unless it has a page :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work with custom collections instead of subfolders in this manner but I'm not sure what your reasons are.

Are you excluding both `README.md` and `readme.md`? Which one is not working?

Comment: I will play with it as collections, currently, README.md or readme.md not ignored inside /myFolder/subFolder/*

however I just found I can call  

`{{ page.dir }}`

Which bring me the directory of files, ex 

`{% for page in site.pages %}    
    {{ page.dir }}
{% endfor %}`

I now need to remove duplicated value (folder name appearing twice)